# A reflection method used in wave equation in one dimension

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I am reading Evans' PDE book about one-dimensional wave equation.

[image]

In the last paragraph, when $h \equiv 0$, it is said the initial displacement $g$ moves in two directions with speed one. I can understand this by the reflection construction, but I don't see this from equation $(10)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h\equiv 0$ then by formula (10),
$$
u(x,t)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{2}[g(x+t)+g(x-t)]\,,&x\ge t\ge 0\\
\frac{1}{2}[g(x+t)-g(t-x)]\,,&0\leq x\leq t\,.\end{array}\right.
$$
At time $t$ the displacement $g(x+t)$ is at $x=-t$ (has moved to the left with speed one). Likewise, the displacement $g(x-t)$ is at $x=t$ (has moved to the right with speed one). Same for the displacement $g(t-x)\,.$ That's all.